# Material Ui CardMedia Component is not loading my picture

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to load a picture using Material UI card component. Everything seems to load except for the actual picture. I have tried all possible ways and other suggestions from the net but no luck.

Here is my code.
I've tried the imageURL, path i even copied the path exactly from the folder structure to see if i wrote it wrong.

````
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import { Button, CardActionArea, CardActions } from '@mui/material';


function DisplayProjectCard(props) {
    return (
    <Card elevation={0}
            sx={{ maxWidth: 645, 
            backgroundColor: "transparent", p:4 }}>
            <CardActionArea>
            <CardMedia
                component="img"
                title="My Next Promo App landing page"
                height="240"
                width="440"
                image="src/static/images/MyNextPromoApp.png"
                alt="Home page of My Next Promo App"
                
        />
            </CardActionArea>
        <CardActions sx={{
            justifyContent:'center'
            }}>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
            View 
        </Button> |
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Github 
        </Button>
        </CardActions>
    </Card>
    );
}
export default DisplayProjectCard```
````

Comment: Check F12 and see if the request is being made, if it is check the url in another tab.

Comment: @mxmissile i got a failed prop type on my image but the docs say utilize the component image

Comment: @mxmissile i also have this message Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received